# Issue in finding parent pom

Tags: java, maven, deployment

I am having an issue during the maven build.I am getting below error when I run my myprj-parent multimodule project as mvn clean instal -PmyProfile:

```
Parent-POM: com.def.bla:alpha:pom:5.5.1 not found in relative path: ../pom.xml
    Retrieving parent-POM: com.def.bla:alpha:pom:5.5.1 for project: com.def:myprj-parent:pom:${VERSION_NUM} from the repository.
    [DEBUG] Trying repository central
    [DEBUG] Connecting to repository: 'central' with url: 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'.
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/def/bla/alpha/5.5.1/alpha-5.5.1.pom
    [DEBUG] Unable to locate resource in repository
    org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to locate resource in repository
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/def/bla/alpha/5.5.1/alpha-5.5.1.pom
```

I have one folder `alpha` outside project, in which I have pom file. When I use command mvn clean install, this create a pom file in .m2 under `com/def/bla/alpha/5.5.1/alpha-5.5.1.pom` depends on the configuration provided.

Not sure how to resolve this error. myprj-parent is my multimodule maven project.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you publish your pom.xml ?

Comment: @fandango How can I publish pom, and which pom should publish in that case?

Comment: Publish your multimodule project pom.xml first, we will see after if we need the others.

Comment: @fandango Problem got resolved, because path was wrong. I placed pom in parallel of my parent project.